# How can I make the enter key on my extended keyboard act as return only?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

For some reason sometimes the numeric <kbd>enter</kbd> key acts as <kbd>return</kbd> and sometimes it doesn't. (I'm talking of the last key on the keyboard, the one with the "k" symbol tilted towards left.)

I'd like to be able to use it as the regular <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Do you know any tip in order to fix this? At the moment it is totally random. My guess is that some software  I use remaps the <kbd>enter</kbd> into <kbd>return</kbd>, but I've not been able to point to which one.

Answer (score 3):

You've got your assumption a tiny bit mixed up. It's not that some software remaps the <kbd>enter</kbd> into <kbd>return</kbd>, it's that some software **treats** an <kbd>enter</kbd> as a <kbd>carriage return</kbd> and some doesn't.

They **are** two different keys with two differnet histories. One is <kbd>enter</kbd> and one is <kbd>carriage return</kbd> and they perform different functions.

I hate referencing wikipedia but hell, here ya go ... [Differences between Enter and Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key#Differences_between_Enter_and_Return).

Usually most programs assume they are the same key - some don't. The AppleScript Editor for example uses <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to force a script parse.

Comment: I can assure you that once it's automagically remapped to act as enter, it is across all programs. iterm2, chrome, textmate etc...

Comment: True, and that's true for any key mapping in OSX but you lose the functionality that the enter key gives you in certain programs

Answer (score 3):

Use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to create a new keyboard layout that maps the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to <kbd>return</kbd>.

Open Ukelele and select *File » New From Current Input Source*. Select *Keyboard » Edit Key…* and confirm to press the key. Then, press <kbd>enter</kbd>. You will be asked what character to replace it with. Enter `&#x000d;` and confirm.

Optionally assign a new name to your keyboard using *Keyboard » Set Keyboard Name…*.

Select *File » Save As…*, navigate to `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts` and assign any name.

Your new keyboard layout will be available in *System Preferences » Language & Text*. If you didn't change the name, you can recognize it by the missing flag icon (it's a keyboard icon instead).

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the nice explanation, I think I may have messed up my configuration. I followed step by step your answer, but the result is that my enter key now maps to the command button. I entered exactly &#000d; but it just resolves to command (⌘)(I am not sure if it was doing it before or not). I can now save a document pressing enter+s which of course is useless!

Comment: @sathia If you press `Return` instead of `Enter` when asked to press the key you want to edit, what does the dialog say is its default mapping? It [looks like this for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdjm9.png), so I wrote that when remapping `Enter`, you need to enter exactly that. I can't imagine why it maps to `Command` for you. To revert changes, just enter `Enter`'s default value (`&#x0003`, displayed in the equivalent dialog). Please try again, it just sounds so odd...

Comment: it's the same here: http://i.imgur.com/gh1hY.png but when I press the enter key, on the virtual keyboard of  Ukelele the command keys are lit... it's crazy!

Comment: @sathia Could you try to reproduce this behavior on a new user account? Maybe something else interferes here.

Comment: good point, i'll try later, now I need to stay logged for a while since I should be working :P I'll update later.