# What is the Mac keyboard key with a symbol ⌅ of an up arrow pointing into a horizontal line?

Tags: mac, keyboard, internationalization, unicode

On a Mac, symbols are often used for keys rather than names. In Adobe Indesign for Mac, the keyboard shortcuts for inserting various break characters are described using what looks like an up arrow / caret / chevron pointing into a flat horizontal line:

[image]

It's the symbol on the right I'm asking about.

After much searching, I found it on the far bottom right of the full-size Apple keyboard. It's the... `enter`-like key (?) in the bottom right of the numeric keypad.

[image]

So two related questions:

- What's it called?
- Is it possible to trigger this key (for use in keyboard shortcuts) when using a keyboard without a numeric keypad (like a wireless keyboard or laptop keyboard)? If so, how?

Comment: For the remapping check this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38011/how-can-i-make-the-enter-key-on-my-extended-keyboard-act-as-return-only

Comment: I've never understood why Apple keyboards print the cloverleaf icon on the command key, but don't print the equivalent icons for option and control on their respective keys.

Comment: @daGUY on my Apple keyboard, the option key has the option symbol, but the label `alt` and not `option`... Seems somewhat random, maybe it depends on what mood the particular product designer was in that morning?

Comment: @user568458 The main label is ⌥ on ISO keyboards and option on ANSI keyboards. "alt" is more like an alternative name for the key (on other platforms).

Comment: For what location is that keyboard built? The US keyboards lack that character entirely.

Comment: It's a UK layout keyboard.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is called **Projective**, with Unicode **U+2305**, and it represents **Enter** which is different to **Carriage Return**, represented with a ↩.

Although most of the time they work in the same way, there is a difference between **Enter** and **Carriage Return**. While **Enter**, in most cases, will make a GUI object operate at its default function, the **Carriage Return** is meant to reset the user's position to the beginning of the line of a text.

Just doing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> should trigger it.

On the *short* keyboards you'll either find the name or the *icon*.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Actually I think the symbol looks more like the "Projective" unicode symbol ⌅ (`⌅` or U+2305) than ⌤ (`⌤`), but I'm more interested in the name of the Mac keyboard key and how to access it when it doesn't have a physical key than the name of the symbol used to name it.

Comment: Okay, so it is the Enter key as opposed to the Return key and can be accessed with Fn + return? Seems to answer the question.

Comment: @user568458 You're completely right. Apparently the U+2324 might be only for the **PC** keyboards. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @LauriRanta When I said fn+Enter I meant the Key usually called Enter.

Comment: +1; note that full-size Mac keyboards do have an actual `Enter` key - as part of the numerical keypad (pressing it has the same effect as `fn+Return`).

Comment: In my testing (OS X 10.9), when adding an `NSMenuItem` with a `keyEquivalent`, the "⌅" "projective" symbol will **not** appear in the menu while the "⌤" **will**. Therefore I think ⌤ is the correct symbol for `Enter`. An Apple designer may have simply printed the "better looking" symbol on the keyboard.

Comment: Note too that the "na1" original Unicode name of ⌤ is "ENTER KEY". Not so for ⌅.

Answer (score 18):

On my Mac, there is a Help menu.  Strange but true!
In Finder Help, searching "symbol" I found "Symbols used in shortcuts".
Your symbol is in there.

[image]

When used in this way, I would just call this symbol by the name "enter".

Comment: As of OS X 10.9: The topic is now titled "What are those symbols shown in menus?" and the line for `Enter` has been _removed_.

Comment: I wonder why they removed it?  Because the "standard" keyboard is now the laptop keyboard, and has no separate Enter key?

Comment: Good question; your guess sounds very plausible. I tried on the public Yosemite (10.10) beta, but it doesn't contain any help yet. I personally don't have any apps that use `Enter`-based shortcuts; the OP mentions that Adobe InDesign contains them - I wonder if the current version of that application now represents them with  `fn + Return`.

Comment: The "Symbols used in shortcuts" support topic (still containing "⌤") is available online here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH10564

Comment: @mklement0 InDesign uses `Enter` for a column break (or page break together with `Shift`), while `Return` is "only" a Paragraph break.

Comment: As of macOS Ventura 13, the document [What are those symbols shown in menus on Mac?](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/what-are-those-symbols-shown-in-menus-cpmh0011/mac) lacks the ⌅ entry. The symbol is still important though since it’s used for the Column/Frame/Page Break shortcuts in Adobe InDesign 2023. The ⌅ symbol is also still found on the non-English versions of the [Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ052LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english) though it‘s (weirdly) omitted and replaced with ”enter” on the US English version.

Answer (score 3):

This is the ⌤ 'Enter Key' character, which is distinct from the similar ⌅ 'Projective' character.

⌤

Unicode Character 'UP ARROWHEAD BETWEEN TWO HORIZONTAL BARS' (U+2324)

Old name: 'ENTER KEY'

Wikipedia says:

> The "Enter" key is commonly labelled with its name in plain text on generic PC keyboards, or with the symbol ⌤ (U+2324 up arrowhead between two horizontal bars) on many Apple Mac keyboards.