# What are these two keys, ⇞ and ⇟?

Tags: keyboard

I see keyboard shortcuts in the menu of Brackets. There are two symbols that look like `up arrow` and `down arrow`, could anyone tell me what they are?

[image]

Comment: This is already answered, technically, in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123568/cant-find-symbol-in-keyboard, and also appears in the help topic mentioned at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/81870/12228 (which is now called "What are those symbols shown in menus?") - though it might be nice if these were easier to search for.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Those are the page-up <kbd>⇞</kbd> and page-down <kbd>⇟</kbd> keys (on keyboards without them, use <kbd>fn</kbd>-Cursor up/down). For a list of other common key symbols, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123568/cant-find-symbol-in-keyboard).